# Jenkins Java VM error when running a Maven test - Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize-128m'

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jvm

The problem is, we changed that from `MaxPermSize-128m` to `MaxPermSize=128m`
but the system keeps giving us that error:
We even restarted Jenkins.
Is it caching something, or there is more than one place where this setting should be changed?

```
[workspace] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize-128m -cp /mnt/www/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.3.jar:/mnt/www/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.1.0/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.2.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /mnt/www/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.1.0 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.28.jar /mnt/www/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.3.jar 55896
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize-128m'
Could not create the Java virtual machine.

ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
```

the output of 'ps -ef | grep java' is:

```
root      3509     1  0 Jul12 ?        00:07:17 /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/exec/elasticsearch-linux-x86-64 /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/elasticsearch.conf wrapper.syslog.ident=elasticsearch wrapper.pidfile=/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/./elasticsearch.pid wrapper.name=elasticsearch wrapper.displayname=ElasticSearch wrapper.daemonize=TRUE wrapper.statusfile=/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/./elasticsearch.status wrapper.java.statusfile=/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/./elasticsearch.java.status wrapper.script.version=3.5.14
root      3511  3509  0 Jul12 ?        00:45:11 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Delasticsearch-service -Des.path.home=/usr/local/share/elasticsearch -Xss256k -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/lib -classpath /usr/local/share/elasticsearch/bin/service/lib/wrapper.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-0.19.11.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/elasticsearch-0.19.11.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/jna-3.3.0.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-analyzers-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-core-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-highlighter-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-memory-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/lucene-queries-3.6.1.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/share/elasticsearch/lib/sigar/sigar-1.6.4.jar -Dwrapper.key=b1QUXxfrVfakmb6w -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.disable_console_input=TRUE -Dwrapper.pid=3509 -Dwrapper.version=3.5.14 -Dwrapper.native_library=wrapper -Dwrapper.service=TRUE -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout=10 -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.ElasticSearchF
jenkins  20372     1  0 08:17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/daemon --name=jenkins --inherit --env=JENKINS_HOME=/mnt/www/jenkins --output=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --pidfile=/var/run/jenkins/jenkins.pid -- /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
jenkins  20373 20372 23 13:20 ?        00:05:51 /usr/bin/java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --httpPort=8080 --ajp13Port=-1
root     29403 28220  0 13:45 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto java
```

Comment: what is the output of 'ps -ef | grep java'

Comment: remove the -XX:MaxPermSize-128m option

Comment: @matheszabi - we tried that, same error message. Its like the changes we make are not applied or taken notice of, or something. Or there is another place where this change should be made?

Comment: @JennyKowalski if you remove that, than you shouldn't have "Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize-128m'" ,

Comment: @Tarlog I've edited the answer, included the output

Comment: @matheszabi - we removed that, but we got the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you expect to set the maximum to a negative value?  I think you wanted

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

-- Update ---

Ok, so you have fixed this, but the build still fails.

Look into the "workspace cleanup plugin", and if it is not installed, install it and activate it.  The [workspace cleanup plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Workspace+Cleanup+Plugin) will remove evidence of prior builds from the workspace before launch.  Odds are that the configuration is stored to file, and then referenced from file immediately prior to launch.

You could move into the workspace directories and grep for the "minus 128" version of the command and alter it by hand, but by using the plugin you also avoid future similar issues.

Comment: as I said, we later changed the "-" to "=" but the system didnt seem to take notice of that change, so this is the main problem - is Jenkins caching data or do we need to change this in more than one place

Comment: Probably.  Take a look into cleaning out the agent build areas.  Jenkins often has to copy stuff into the agent (parameters, source code, etc) areas before launching executables there.

Comment: After having refreshed the cached content, it worked, thanks!